# GIT on Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, git

I am running Debian 9, vanilla install.

My hardware is HP Z230-SFF Workstation, Intel Core i7-4790, GPU Nvidia Quadro K620.

Normally on Boot I get the following error: tpm: tpm0 a error(7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value (I don't think this is related to my question here; but just mentioning it in case it was related in a way I am unaware of).

My problem is when trying to install git: I have seen posts related to this same problem on Jessie; however, none of the solutions mentioned there fixes the problem on stretch. I get the same dependencies error:

I run Synaptic GUI, and when I mark the package git, I get the following:

```
git:
 Depends: liberror-perl  but it is not installable
 Depends: git-man but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: git-man but it is not going to be installed
 Recommends: patch  but it is not installable
```

Here is my `sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

Running `apt-cache policy git` :

```
git: Installed: (none) 
Candidate: 1:2.11.0-3+deb9u2 
  Version table : 
 *** 1:2.11.0-3+deb9u2 500 
      500 security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

Running `ls /var/lib/dpkg/ | grep status` :

```
status 
status-old
```

Running `apt-get update` :

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                        
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease     
Hit:4 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease          
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:6 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: run `apt-get update`
 first

Comment: already tried that several times

Comment: Please put here the sources.list in text; copy&paste and not an image. Also add the name of packages  you installed out of Debian repositories.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have *never* had any problems whatsoever installing/using `git` on neither Jessie or Stretch.

Comment: that image is unreadable.  [Please don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself and format it as code with the `{}` icon in the editor.

Comment: root@debian:/home/asabbah# apt-cache policy git
git:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.11.0-3+deb9u2
  Version table:
     1:2.11.0-3+deb9u2 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages

Comment: root@debian:/home/asabbah# ls /var/lib/dpkg/ | grep status
status
status-old

Comment: Please stop posting your updates here in the comments, and instead put them in the question where they are easy for everyone to read.

Comment: ls /etc/apt/preferences.d/ , it is empty

Comment: I am running the gui for Synaptic, I mark git, and when it goes resolving the dependencies it gets back with the message I posted above

Comment: I noted that the post was put on-hold as not reproducible; I don't mind giving anyone in the forum access to my machine on a specific time if you wish to do further checks.

Comment: Your `apt-cache policy git` should have returned not only the `debian-security stretch/updates/main` package but also the original one in `debian stretch/main`. When you ran `apt-get update` did you get any messages or other errors?

Comment: I've got Stretch here. With your sources.list file, even allowing for Chrome, I get your `apt-get update` but I don't get your `apt-cache` result. Please could you just recheck that what you've given us here is exactly what you get. (If necessary update your question to reflect the (new) reality.)